# center tag interfering with image

Tags: html, css

I have this particular HTML code. I want the "ironman" image to appear on left but the 'center' tag is interfering with it. Is there any way to make the image appear on left instead of center without moving it outside the div?

```
<center>
    <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="iron">
            <img class="ironman" data-aos="zoom-in" src="assets/ironman.png">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h2>ABC</h2>
            <p>ABC</p>
            <p>ABC</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: You could start by getting rid of `<center>` which was superseded by CSS 1 in 1996.

Comment: I get the impression that you omitted a bunch of relevant CSS from the question that styles the other elements you included.

Comment: want to do only image appear on the left side or want to do image on left and text on right?

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the center tag set the `text-align` property to `center` so that forces all divs to center its content, and the code below just overrides this behaviour

```
<div class="iron" style="text-align: left;">
```

**important Note**
it is not a best practice to use `center` tag since it has been deprecated long time ago,

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first remove `center` tag this will place your image on Left side of webpage by default

```
<div class="flip-card">
        <div class="iron">
            <img class="ironman" data-aos="zoom-in" src="assets/ironman.png">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h2>ABC</h2>
            <p>ABC</p>
            <p>ABC</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="iron">
            <img class="ironman" data-aos="zoom-in" src="assets/ironman.png">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h2>ABC</h2>
            <p>ABC</p>
            <p>ABC</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.center{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

this is the best way to center it all

Answer (score -2):

center tag is deprecated in html5

use css instead

```css
.flip-card .flip-card-inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="iron">
      <img class="ironman" data-aos="zoom-in" src="assets/ironman.png">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <h2>ABC</h2>
        <p>ABC</p>
        <p>ABC</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What CSS? This doesn't answer the question, it's a comment.